# What is the equivalent of Array.prototype.map() for objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to take some some objects from an original object into an array variable.

```
console.log("news len", news["articles"].length); // this comes out to 9

for(var a in news["articles"]) {
    var results = [];
    results.push({
        title:news["articles"][a]["title"],
        subtitle: news["articles"][a]["description"],
        item_url:news["articles"][a]["title"],
        image_url:news["articles"][a]["urlToImage"],
    });
}
console.log("results len",results.length); //only contains one entry
```

Is there another way to accomplish this, and if not what am I doing wrong?

Using Node js if that helps any.

Comment: can you add your object news ,how does the content look in it

Comment: It looks like news["articles"] is an array, so we not just map with that?

Comment: to prevent some errors, like reinitializing empty array, i suggest to declare all variables in advance at the beginning of the code, directly after the functions - this includes variable for `for`, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use map directly and return an object in the callback for a new array

```
var results = news.articles.map(function (a) {
        return {
            title: a.title,
            subtitle: a.description,
            item_url: a.title,
            image_url: a.urlToImage
        };
    };
```

Comment: Yup, I was using the news object itself instead of news.articles. Lapse of thinking on my part, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that each iteration of your loop re-sets `results` to an empty array:

```
var results=[];
```

If you move that statement *before* your loop, you will get something closer to what you want.

That said, it looks like `news["articles"]` already *is* an array, so you can probably just use `Array.prototype.map`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = [];
news["articles"].map(function(val,idx){
    results.push({
       title: val["title"],
       //etc
    }
});
```